# Use ALFA in standalone mode

Tags: authorization, xacml, alfa, abac

The DSL ALFA by Axiomatics is only provided as an eclipse plugin. Is it possible to use it in standalone mode? There is a Main class bundled in the jar but I have had no luck getting it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible just yet but it will be in the near future. Stay tuned for further [developments](http://www.axiomatics.com)

### EDIT

A standalone compiler is now available in ALFA 1.2

Comment: Standalone compiler is now available with ALFA version 1.2 from Axiomatics

Comment: Thanks @KeerthiS. Just added

Comment: Having trouble finding a link to that stand-alone compiler, @neonidian... got a link?

Comment: Go to www.axiomatics.com

Comment: @gap fill in this form at https://www.axiomatics.com/alfa/ and you would be able to get the ALFA compiler along with additional ALFA components by email (usually)

Comment: Unfortunately, it is only offered to paying customers.